# Как выбрать последнею строку в Mysql и заполнение одно из полей без перезагрузки?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Есть скрипт который раз в 10 секунд добавляет значения акции в базу данных, на другой странице есть небольшое текстовое поле, теперь как в него автоматически записать значение только что пришедшего числа?

Comment: дополните вопрос вашими ответами из комментариев (к ответу), чтобы вопрос стал полезен другим посетителям сообщества.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select `you_table`.`id` as `last_id` from `you_table` order by `id` desc limit 1
```

ну и результат искомое значение. или как вариант писать это число после insert в временую переменную, или если это в рамках одной сессии то в сессию.

Comment: С этим разобрались, но как теперь с помощью Javascript получить это значение и вывести в input type text?

Comment: стесняюсь спросить зачем js? можно просто при рендере страницы 
`<input name='test' type='text' value='<?php echo $this->getLastId() ?>'>`
где $this->getLastId() это либо метод возвращающий последнию строку, либо может быть заменён на переменную которая содержит это значение.

Comment: Просто есть 2 страницы, 1 которая добавляет в БД число, на второй существует текстовое поле, мне туда и нужно передать

Comment: 2 страница она должна работать без перезагрузке на ajax или без разницы?

Comment: Без перезагрузки

Comment: Каждые 10 секунд делать на сервер запрос к скрипту с сервера отдавать число в формате json масива или просто число. и потом по id устанавливать значение input. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ тут можно более подробно узнать.

Comment: да незашто но всё равно я бы выбрал для начала вариант с перезагрузкой страницы

Comment: Просто пользователь будет работать с заполнением форм, имя, фамилия, счет и т.п., и нужно чтобы эти часть данных приходила автоматически, будет немного неудобно если страница будет перезагружатся раз 100 на дню

Comment: Ну не видел пользователя который не перезагружал сам страницу в течения дня работая с ней.